# Is there any explanation of what the one- and two-headed monster statues at the entrances to Kraid's and Ridley's hideouts represent?

Tags: video-games, art, metroid

In the *Metroid* games taking place on Zebes, the entrances to the "hideouts" of the minibosses Kraid and Ridley are often decorated with monstrous heads—a single-headed, blue monster at Kraid's hideout entrance and a dual-headed red one at Ridleys.  Are there any indications in *Metroid* lore of what kind(s) of creatures these are, or if they actually represent (real in-universe) alien creatures at all?

Here are their appearances in the original NES *Metroid*, in which Samus has to step into the open mouths to the take the elevators down—descending into the bowels of the beasts.

[image: Kraid's hideout (NES)]

[image: Ridley's hideout (NES)]

Apart from the differences in color (which may be meaningless in universe) and number of heads (a much more curious difference), these appear to be the same kind of monster.  The heads and mouths are essentially the same, and so are the claws.  (The clawed foot is nowhere near as obvious on the red creature as on the blue, but it's there, behind and above the lower head.)

Only the single-headed monster at the entrance to Kraid's hideout appears in *Super Metroid*.  (There are some other creature mouths to be entered in various locations, however.  Getting to Ridley involves going through what appears to be a giant stone version of Ridley's own mouth.)

[image: Kraid's hideout (SNES)]

Both of them return in the remake of the original game, *Metroid:  Zero Mission*, albeit with a very different esthetic from the other appearances.

[image: Kraid's hideout (Zero Mission)]

[image: Ridley's hideout (Zero Mission)]

What is known from the lair about the creatures depicted in these statues?